# java.lang.illegalstateexception unable to retrieve entitymanagerfactory for unitname null

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I write Entity.jar .It's EJB Module contain entity class and etitydao class. When i run it on GlassFish , i have error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:158)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTransactionScopedTxCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:281)
    at com.styl.thincapayment.dao.impl.DataAccessImpl.insertToDatabase(DataAccessImpl.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

**I think it comes from persistence.xml . I put it wrong place. How to resolve this problem.**

- I put persistence file in entities/src/resources/persistence.xml . I use Maven to manage project
- Declaration EntityManager:

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="entities")

  protected EntityManager entityManager;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`persistence.xml` should be put inside the folder `CLASS_PATH_ROOT/META-INF`.

If you are using Maven 's [standard project layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) , the path should be `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

Comment: Thanks Ken Chan a lot . I fixed it